# Looping through alternative (every other) DataGridView column

Tags: .net, vb.net, loops, datagridview

I know you can loop through alternating rows of a `DataGridView` but I can't find any help on looping through alternating columns. I've tried using the code below which sounds like it would work on paper but keeps breaking.

```
    Dim i As Integer

    i = i + 1

    For i = 1 To 5
        Dim value6 As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(i).Value
        Select Case value6
            Case "1"
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(i).Style.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
            Case "2"
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(i).Style.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse
            Case "3"
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(i).Style.BackColor = Color.Orange
        End Select
    Next i
```

It keeps breaking when it gets to a column with a date because it's not an integer.

I've inserted a picture of the `DataGridView` below but I want the code to loop through every other column with an integer and read the value, starting at column(2) ending at column(6).

Any help would be appreciated!

[DataGridView Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybLnf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, If you're starting at column index 2 you'll need to change the number for the start of the loop. To get the loop to iterate over alternate columns, add 'Step 2' to the end of your for statement like this:

```
For i = 2 To 6 Step 2
    Dim value6 As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(i).Value
    Select Case value6
        Case "1"
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(i).Style.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
        Case "2"
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(i).Style.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse
        Case "3"
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(i).Style.BackColor = Color.Orange
    End Select
Next i
```

That should do it.

The 'Step' keyword causes the index variable to increase after each iteration by the number you specify.

Comment: I had to change `For i = 2 to *6* Step 2` for it to work but this is exactly what i was looking for thanks David!